# How can I disable locations in Android 11(API 30) using adb shell command

Tags: android, shell, adb

The following commands do not disable location services on API 30. Although they do work on other API levels.

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network
```

They do not throw any error message, but they do not turn off the location services either.

Comment: Our sister site [android.se] might be a better fit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, posted the question in https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sahithiDK does the answer below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

These are the commands you should use

(to enable):

```
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3
```

(to disable):

```
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0
```